# how to show the actual modulepath?

Tags: junit4, java-11, jgiven

For debugging I have a need to see the actual modulepath. How can I print it out at runtime?

The problem: Using ServiceLoader to load a module against a defined API works fine in normal runtime environment but not in testing. I'd got to find out why.

As I am new to ServiceLoader, it may not to be enough that a provider module can be found on modulepath. However, my first question is: is it on modulepath even in test environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to check the presence of a module, you can straight-forwardly check the presence of a module, e.g.

```java
String moduleName = "java.compiler";
ModuleLayer.boot().findModule(moduleName)
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        m -> System.out.println(m + " loaded via " + m.getClassLoader()),
        () -> System.out.println(moduleName + " not found"));
```

When the module is not present, you can check module path using the non-standard system property,

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("jdk.module.path"));
```

Besides possibility of a mismatching path, it’s worth checking the [context loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()) of each envi­ron­ment if loading a service fails in one environment, as the [method `ServiceLoader.load(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.Class)) uses the [context loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()) for searching.

Also check that the module’s classes are not accidentally provided on the old class path.

Comment: Thank you, Holger. Now I can see that the module is - for what reason ever - not on the module-path, even though its dependency is mentioned in pom.xml. I am a step further in debugging.